# flask session variable doesn't change after a request

Tags: python, session, flask

I want to update the variable('CAPTCHA_NUM') when I visit the url('/captcha') and get this variable in templates:

```
@app.route('/captcha')
def captcha():
    from captcha.image import ImageCaptcha
    from random import random
    image = ImageCaptcha()
    x = int(round(random() * 10000))
    if x < 1000: x += 1000
    session['CAPTCHA_NUM'] = x
    return image.generate(str(session['CAPTCHA_NUM']), 'png').getvalue()
```

But each time when I refresh my page(visit this url), the captcha updates, however the `session['CAPTCHA_NUM']` doesn't.

For example, first I get the captcha `7530`, then I refresh `register.html`(which visits the url) and captcha is updated but the `session['CAPTCHA_NUM']` still is `7530`.

And this is where I visit the url(captcha):

register.html

```
<img id="vcode" src="{{url_for('captcha')}}" alt="captcha" />
```

and I get `session['CAPTCHA_NUM']` in `validate_capcha()`:

```
<input type="text" name="captcha" onblur="validate_captcha()" />
```

=================Solution========================

In the official doc of [flask session](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#standard-context), it says:

`This variable is unavailable if the template was rendered without an active request context.`

I just change the `src` attribute of `img` tag, and apparently this isn't an active request context.

And finally I put the captcha validation part at the server-side so that I can avoid this problem.

Comment: That should works, try use debug mode and check the error message?

Comment: @KevinGuan I print session['CAPTCHA_NUM'] in console and it's right. But  in my register.html page, the variable doesn't change until I revisit the url when it is supposed to be updated to a newer one:(

Comment: So there is no error here, but session didn't change?

Comment: @KevinGuan In `captcha()` function, session changes. But In `register.html`, it doesn't.

Comment: @KevinGuan I guess check it on server side is the only choice.

Comment: will it work if I add a param for the url_for('captcha', 'id:11')?

Answer (score 0):

if you use visit `http://***.com/captcha` it won't refresh.
you Need to give it a param so it will refresh

at first you write

```
url_for('.captcha')
```

change it to

```
url_for('.captcha',t=some_random_value)
```

then it will refresh
cause it generate a url like this:  `http://***.com/captcha?t=some_random_value`